# Change CSS from iframe error

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I would like to change the css from a iframe with jQuery. I used the following code:

Iframe:

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="https://source.com"></iframe>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery("#myiframe").contents().find("body").css('background-color', 'black');
```

But when I run the code, comes the following console error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Who has the solution to my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: So it's not possible to change the css on the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

The iframe is not part of your page, so you can't change the style, you can apply styles just for **iframe tag**, for example to make a custom scrollbar etc.